# Determining if the neighbours of a value in an array add up to a set value?

Tags: java, arrays, math, addition

I'm making a simple addition maths game and was wondering how to implement the following.

Say I have this array:

`int[] numbers = { 9, 2, 1, 1, 2, 9 };`

and I want the user to insert a value of, say, `2` somewhere in the array so that a bunch of *consecutively placed* numbers in the array **including the newly placed value** add up to a target value, say, `8`. I'll call this combination of numbers a *combo*.

I want the user to be able to place the 8 anywhere in that array. since `2 + 1 + 1 + 2 = 6` the user should be able to place it anywhere in between those outer `9`'s.

A proper placement could be `{9, 2, *2*, 1, 1, 2, 9}` or `{9, *2*, 2, 1, 1, 2, 9}` for example.

Now the issue I am having implementing this is that I can only get it to work when you place the `2` on the *outer sides* of a combo, so like in the second example above this paragraph, and not like in the first one.

I do this by:

1. Looking up the value from the array at `startIndex`
2. Add this value to the `currentSum`
3. See if the `currentSum == targetValue` : combo found
4. Else if the `currentSum > targetValue` : combo not found
5. Else set `startIndex += 1` (or -1 if placed at the other end) and repeat

But that only solves the issue when the newly placed value is at the outer bounds of a combo.

I realise that I could brute-force my way around this problem by adding up each the contents of each potential sub-array containing the newly-placed value, and then seeing if one of those adds up to the target value of `8`, but I am looking for something more elegant.

Comment: `startIndex` is the index at which the element was inserted, right?

Comment: That is right indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making an array of the summations left and right of your filled in value, stopping the calculation once you reach (or exceed) your target. In this case, I'm using -1 to mark values that don't need to be considered. Consider your example:

```
nums = { 9, 2, *2*, 1, 1, 2, 9 }
```

becomes

```
sums = { -1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 4, -1 }
```

Now, you can either find (8 - value) in this sequence, meaning your inserted value is at the start or end, or a combination of two values to the right and left of your insertion index that add up to (8 - value). Those are the indexes you're looking for. The reason I'm not counting the inserted value for the sums is that that would cause it to be counted double; it's easier to add it after the fact.

The useful part of this is that you're always only checking around the inserted value.
Consider the next example, still looking for an 8:

```
nums = { 3, 4, 3, *2*, 1, 2, 4, 1, 5 }
```

becomes

```
sums = { -1, 7, 3, *0*, 1, 3, 7, -1, -1 }
```

While your array is still 9 values long, you already know you only have 6 of those left to check.

Comment: Good answer but still not fully satisfied; whilst this noticably cuts down on the amount of values you'd have to brute-force check, you'd still have to brute-force check. This is absolutely code that would be sufficient enough but out of pure curiousity I'm not marking this as solved.